# The most common Bluetooth profile for implementing modern TV remote control functionality

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm exploring a possibility to emulate Bluetooth TV remote control. And I faced a problem that I can't find any information about the type of Bluetooth, which TV manufacturers use in their devices. If they use Bluetooth Classic (BR/EDR), then I have to implement either **AVRCP** or **HID** profiles to fulfil TV remote control functionality. If they use Bluetooth LE, then I have to implement **HOGP** profile. So, could you suggest to me which Bluetooth profile is mostly implemented in modern TVs with Bluetooth support? If someone has experience with a particular TV model, which supports Bluetooth, then I will be also appreciated for any information about Bluetooth, which is installed there.

Comment: I afraid there is no such statistics. I personally would implement both. However, AVRCP and HID requires work on L2CAP level so your OS must allow to do that. BLE much easy to implement.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for your answer. I don't expect official statistics, but at least personal experience to not waste time for development unnecessary functionality for a major part of modern TVs and choose an appropriate Bluetooth chip.

Comment: I did not mean official statistic as well. Any way, BLE looks better as start because it really easy to implement. You can add AVRCP/HID later if got such requests. All that is just IMHO.